# creating an EPSG:28992 map using openlayers3

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

I am trying to create an openlayers3 map using a custom wmts layer on eps:28992 setting. I have used openlayers 2 before, but i am not succeding in this.

I have tried adding the eps layer to the proj, however it does not seem to do anything, there is an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null.
And none of the tiles are requested.

```
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:28992');
var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
var resolutions = [3440.640, 1720.320, 860.160, 430.080, 215.040, 107.520, 53.760, 26.880, 13.440, 6.720, 3.360, 1.680, 0.840, 0.420, 0.210];
var matrixIds = new Array(26);
   for (var i=0; i<26; ++i) {
    matrixIds[i] = "EPSG:28992:" + i;
}

var attribution = new ol.Attribution({
  html: 'Tiles &copy; <a href="http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/' +
      'services/Demographics/USA_Population_Density/MapServer/">ArcGIS</a>'
});

lonlat = result.center.split(',');


var map = new ol.Map({


    view: new ol.View({
        center: [lonlat[0],lonlat[1]],
        zoom: result.zoom
    }),

    layers: [
         new ol.layer.Tile({
          opacity: 0.7,
          source: new ol.source.WMTS({
            attributions: [attribution],
            url: "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/wmts/",
            name: "Basis Registratie Topografie",
            layer: "brtachtergrondkaart",
            matrixSet: "EPSG:28992",
            format: 'image/png',
            projection: projection,
            tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
              origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
              resolutions: resolutions,
              matrixIds: matrixIds
            }),
            style: 'default'
          })
        })
    ],
    target: target
});
```

The resolution en matrixIds worked in openlayers2 so i directly copied them, I think i am missing something very small does any1 have an idea?

p.s. i added the epsg:28992 to the proj4.js with the following line:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992","+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs");
```

regards Casper

Comment: Check out if this helps you: https://github.com/bartvde/PDOK-OpenLayers3

Comment: Thnx for the demo, it is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `ol.proj.Projection#getExtent()` will return `null` for projections that are configured from Proj4js. You don't need Proj4js for your map to work, but you'll need the correct origin for the tile grid. The easiest way to configure a WMTS layer is to request the capabilities (http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/wmts/?request=GetCapabilities) and use `ol.format.WMTSCapabilities` and `ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities` to create the options for the `ol.source.WMTS` instance. But you can also configure your layer manually. Looking at the GetCapabilities response, I see that the correct origin is `[-285401.92 903402.0]`.